# How to use the $ in Jupyter-notebook Markdown code snippets

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, markdown

I am new to Jupyter-notebook and despite browsing the web and stack-overflow, I wasn't able to find an answer. As well in introducing tutorials to Jupyter-notebook.
I'm sure the issue is trivial but not yet enough for me ...

When I write `<code> $ </code>`, this last command does not exit anything until a second $ written later on in the text (see the image: [dollar issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlgAh.png)).
It looks like this second `<code> $ </code>` in the text is the exit.

Can someone explain to me how to write the  `$`  in Jupyter-notebook Markdown code-snippets please? (it properly works in this very editor!)

Answer (score 2):

This is a rendering issue. They are working on it:
https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/6774
https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1080

Comment: Alright thank you for the good piece of information